# How to solve python error in docker - Failed building wheel for pyarrow?

Tags: docker, build, bamboo, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am trying to build in Bamboo and got this error,

```
Failed to build pyarrow
21-Sep-2022 06:24:14    ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
21-Sep-2022 06:24:15    The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade pip && pip install pyarrow' returned a non-zero code: 1
21-Sep-2022 06:24:15    =An error occurred when executing task 'DockerBuild'.
```

This error occurs only when I add pyarrow or fastparquet in requirements.txt.

This is my requirements.txt file:

```
requests
urllib3
fastapi
uvicorn[standard]
gunicorn
pytest-cov
prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator
prometheus_client
fastapi-health
python-decouple
ecs-logging
fastapi_health
psycopg2
arrow
anyio
asgiref
certifi
charset-normalizer
click
colorama
h11
idna
python-dotenv
pydantic
sniffio
starlette
typing_extensions
datetime
fastapi_resource_server
sendgrid
PyJWT==2.4.0
bcrypt==3.2.
cryptography==37.0.2
passlib
jose
jira
adal==1.2.7
aiohttp==3.8.1
aiosignal==1.2.0
async-timeout==4.0.2
azure-core==1.25.0
azure-identity==1.10.0
azure-storage-blob==12.13.1
pandas==1.4.4
multidict==6.0.2
numpy==1.23.2
ordered-set==4.1.0
oauthlib==3.2.0
packaging==21.3
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.2.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
six==1.16.0
yarl==1.8.1
```

Below is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.4-alpine3.15

RUN adduser -D pythonwebapi


WORKDIR /home/pythonwebapi
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY logger_config.py logger_config.py

RUN echo 'http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk upgrade && apk add make gcc g++
RUN apk update
RUN apk add libffi-dev
RUN apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache musl-dev linux-headers g++
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install arrow && pip install pyarrow
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && pip install gunicorn 
RUN apk del gcc g++ make

COPY app app
COPY init_app.py ./

ENV FLASK_APP init_app.py

RUN chown -R pythonwebapi:pythonwebapi ./
RUN chown -R 777 ./
USER pythonwebapi


EXPOSE 8000 7000
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn","--timeout", "1000","init_app:app","-k","uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker","-b","0.0.0.0"]
```

Is this error because of the python image?
I am still learning docker so not sure what went wrong here. Can anyone please help me in understanding this?

Comment: The error says "Please install rust". How about adding rust before running pip install?

Comment: @KotaMori On adding rust in requirements.txt, still the same error pops up

Comment: @potterson11 - Adding `rust` to `requirements.txt` won't do anything. Rust is *not* a Python packages but a programming language that apparently needs to be installed on the hosting machine before you can install `maturin` (this is what your logs say: `Please install rust (https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install)`).

Comment: I think you'll have a hard time installing pyarrow on alpine. There's no wheel provided for that system (https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/9.0.0/#files). So pyarrow we'll have to be installed 'from source'. And for that to happen you have to install a lot of system dependencies that are not present on light weight system like alpine. This might help https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/python.html#docker-examples. Alternatively use `python:3.10.4-slim-bullseye` as a base image.

Comment: @0x26res I have built it from source now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I have changed the docker file and built it from source since I came to know that pyarrow wheels are not provided for alpine.

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine

RUN adduser -D pythonwebapi


WORKDIR /home/pythonwebapi
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY logger_config.py logger_config.py
RUN echo 'http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --no-cache build-base \
        autoconf \
        bash \
        bison \
        boost-dev \
        cmake \
        flex \
        libressl-dev \
        zlib-dev

RUN  apk add make gcc g++
RUN apk add libffi-dev
RUN apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt && pip install gunicorn 
RUN apk del gcc g++ make

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir six pytest numpy cython
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pandas

ARG ARROW_VERSION=3.0.0
ARG ARROW_SHA1=c1fed962cddfab1966a0e03461376ebb28cf17d3
ARG ARROW_BUILD_TYPE=release

ENV ARROW_HOME=/usr/local \
    PARQUET_HOME=/usr/local

#Download and build apache-arrow
RUN mkdir -p /arrow \
    && wget -q https://github.com/apache/arrow/archive/apache-arrow-${ARROW_VERSION}.tar.gz -O /tmp/apache-arrow.tar.gz \
    && echo "${ARROW_SHA1} *apache-arrow.tar.gz" | sha1sum /tmp/apache-arrow.tar.gz \
    && tar -xvf /tmp/apache-arrow.tar.gz -C /arrow --strip-components 1 \
    && mkdir -p /arrow/cpp/build \
    && cd /arrow/cpp/build \
    && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$ARROW_BUILD_TYPE \
        -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/ssl \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$ARROW_HOME \
        -DARROW_WITH_BZ2=ON \
        -DARROW_WITH_ZLIB=ON \
        -DARROW_WITH_ZSTD=ON \
        -DARROW_WITH_LZ4=ON \
        -DARROW_WITH_SNAPPY=ON \
        -DARROW_PARQUET=ON \
        -DARROW_PYTHON=ON \
        -DARROW_PLASMA=ON \
        -DARROW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
        .. \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install \
    && cd /arrow/python \
    && python setup.py build_ext --build-type=$ARROW_BUILD_TYPE --with-parquet \
    && python setup.py install \
    && rm -rf /arrow /tmp/apache-arrow.tar.gz

COPY app app
COPY init_app.py ./

ENV FLASK_APP init_app.py

RUN chown -R pythonwebapi:pythonwebapi ./
RUN chown -R 777 ./
USER pythonwebapi

EXPOSE 8000 7000
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn","--timeout", "5000","init_app:app","-k","uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker","-b","0.0.0.0","-m 3000m"]
```

Comment: Just to be clear, pyarrow is supported on alpine. But pyarrow doesn't provide wheels for that specific system (meaning you have to build it yourself)

Comment: @0x26res Understood. Changed my answer to correct information